# How to setup a tunneled connection to a NAS?

Tags: vpn, network-attached-storage

While looking into alternatives for Dropbox I explored the idea of a NAS.
It would be easy to hook up the NAS to a broadband connection and have the users access the files.

However, 

- The data needs to be encrypted on the NAS itself (in case it gets stolen).

- The connection to the NAS needs to be secure (VPN?).

- The drive needs to appear as a drive under windows (so no https).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance, I can't seem to find the final solution!

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look at ... http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/01/create-an-encrypted-samba-share/